# How to start an app on boot with flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, boot

I'm trying to find an example (or generally figure out) how to create a flutter app that starts when the mobile phone boots up.

Are there any flutter/dart specific examples or packages for this?

If not, how would I have to implement such a functionality? (I've found some java examples for Android, but I would prefer a way to do it with dart that also works on iOS)

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: @dazza5000 an app that receives signals (similar to a chat application), which needs to react on them. I might be able to do it with push-notifications (Firebase?) but I'm not sure about that yet. But yeah, basically, app receives information -> needs to react.

Comment: The most reliable way would be to use Push Notifications to signal that the app needs to do some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, iOS does not allow to have this kind of behaviour.

Additional info you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1)

> **voip** (from Background modes)
>
> The app provides Voice-over-IP services. Apps with this key are
>   automatically launched after system boot so that the app can
>   reestablish VoIP services. Apps with this key are also allowed to play
>   background audio.